# How to pass a Model class as parameter so that function can call the class's method?

Tags: php, laravel-5

Tough I'm using this in Laravel 5, but I think it's also a generic php question.

I think the code in `index()` function is just pretty generic, I probably will be using the same code in just every `index()` function in every model.

I have them refactored and left one last part here:

```
public function index() {
    $users = User::paginate($this->paginateItemLimit());
    return $this->successResponder->respondWithPaginator($users);
}
```

Now how do I make one step further to simply make a call:

```
public function index() {
    $this->modelIndex(Model);
}
```

I was thinking perhaps class can be passed by `User::class`, but how do I utilised it in the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create your own basic controller (like BaseController), extend it from Controller and add there a method like

```
public function modelIndex($model) {
return $this->successResponder->respondWithPaginator(
$model::paginate($this->paginateItemLimit())
);
}
```

Comment: Ah, it's so easy, as straight forward as that. I trapped myself in the iteration of Complex Syntax. Thank you.